# gstreamer split multi-channel wav file into separate channels and encode each channel as mp3, alac etc and save to file

Tags: audio, mp3, wav, gstreamer

I need to split a multi-channel wav file and encode each channel into mp3 files.

I know about deinterleave plugin for gtresamer, but I am not sure how to use it for wav file and how to encode the channel stream.

I prefer gtreamer(or ffmpeg) based solution, as I need to limit I/O. I.e, I don't want the intermediate single channel wav files to be written to the storage.

ffmpeg can be used for this in [this way](https://superuser.com/questions/601972/ffmpeg-isolate-one-audio-channel). But, both the switches are not available in [ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/libav/+bug/1004174) ffmpeg.

snsonic's solutions threw the following error:

```
(gst-launch-0.10:2218): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstpng.so': libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...

Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0: Internal data flow error.

Additional debug info:

gstwavparse.c(1982): gst_wavparse_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstWavParse:wavparse0:

streaming task paused, reason not-linked (-1)

ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.

Setting pipeline to NULL ...

Freeing pipeline ...



    (gst-launch-0.10:2218): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_unref: assertion `GST_CAPS_REFCOUNT_VALUE (caps) > 0' failed
```

When I tested using a single channel wav file without deinterleave, the mp3 file was created but it had only noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the number of channels in advance?
If you use gst-launch you can dome something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="xx.wav" ! wavparse ! deinterleave name=d \
  d.src_01 ! <encoder> ! filesink location="out1.mp3" \
  d.src_02 ! <encoder> ! filesink location="out2.mp3"
```

and so on. If you don't know the number of channels beforehand, you'll need to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg could probably do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to know in advance how many channel the wav file has.
You need **sox** installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1

fbname=$(basename "$INPUT" .wav)

N=`soxi -c $INPUT`

for i in $(seq 1 $N)
do
    sox ${INPUT} "${fbname}-${i}.wav" remix $i
    avconv -i "${fbname}-${i}.wav" -f mp2 "${fbname}-${i}.mp3"
    rm ${fbname}-${i}.wav

done
```

You may want to replace *avconv* with *ffmpeg*, depending on the distribution you are working on.